# Pi Hole suddenly stopped working

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-stretch, pi-hole

I've been running Pi-Hole on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ continuously for a few weeks now. Everything worked great but all of a sudden it stopped working.

My devices don't connect to the internet as if they're trying to look up a non-existent DNS. I cannot access the web portal, I cannot ping to the Raspberry Pi from other devices, I cannot ping other devices and websites from it. My router doesn't even show the Pi as being connected to it, which is strange because according to the Pi, it is connected to my router.

What could be wrong with it and how can I solve it?

NB: The Pi is connected via Wi-Fi. I'm using the 2019-04-08 stretch version. I'm only using it for Pi-Hole. Restarting didn't work. I connected it via HDMI, everything seems fine except that I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Is the Pi connected via WiFi or Ethernet?  What version of the operating system?  Where you doing anything (or had anything else) on the Pi other than Pi-Hole?  Have you tried pulling the power and restarting?  Have you tried plugging a monitor in to see if the screen shows anything?

Comment: @Andyroo It's connected via Wifi.I'm using the 2019-04-08 stretch version. I'm only using it for pi-hole. Restarting didn't work. I connected it via HDMI, everything seems fine except that I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Has the Pi changed it’s IP address?

Comment: @Andyroo My router did reset itself. So I changed the SSID and password back to how it was when it was working, clicked on forget network on the pi and typed the password in again. But, the pi hasn't changed it's IP

Comment: Can you access the portal directly from the Pi if you go to 127.0.0.1/admin/

Comment: This sounds like your using a dynamic IP address, which will change every few days.  Rebooting the router is a very good way to have the router forget the current IP address and assign a new one to the PI.

Comment: @user3629249 Rebooting the router to get a new ip address does not help much. The ip address is requested by the client.

Answer (score 1):

My PiHole once had a similar problem - it couldn't work as a DNS server because it didn't have the right time.
I googled for a solution and eventually found one - it was installing ntp on the Pi, then forcing “nameserver 8.8.8.8” on /etc/resolv.conf (and changing the right of this file to 555 to avoid system modification each time).
Hope it will help.